# Checking current mongodb logging level

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Does anyone know how to check the logging level in mongodb? I see how to set it, but I'm not sure what the current setting on my server is.

Answer (score 16):

You can use the [`getParameter`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getParameter/) command:

```
> use admin;
> db.runCommand({getParameter: 1, logLevel: 1});
{ "logLevel" : 0, "ok" : 1 }
```

Note: as the docs say, it doesn't matter what the values are for those two keys. Or, as Stennie said in the comments, just:

```
> db.adminCommand({getParameter: 1, logLevel: 1});
{ "logLevel" : 0, "ok" : 1 }
```

Comment: FYI, instead of "use admin; db.runCommand(..)" you can use `db.adminCommand(...)`. eg: `db.adminCommand({getParameter: 1, logLevel: 1})`

Answer (score 9):

To basically get the current profiling level use:

```
db.getProfilingLevel()
```

Which returns the current level as in integer.

For more information use:

```
db.getProfilingStatus()
```

Which has both the profiling level and the slow query/operation threshold.

Comment: The db.getProfiling* commands return the [`profile` level](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#profiling-levels), which can be set differently per database (and have global defaults). The [`logLevel`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/parameters/#param.logLevel) value is a global parameter separate to profiling.

Comment: Asks for loglevel, answer is about profiling level. Answer gets upvotes. lol

Comment: wrong and terrible answer

Answer (score 9):

Now in version 3, you can use

[db.getLogComponents()](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.getLogComponents/#db.getLogComponents)

> New in version 3.0.
>
> Returns the current verbosity settings. The verbosity settings
>   determine the amount of Log Messages that MongoDB produces for each
>   log message component.
>
> If a component inherits the verbosity level of its parent,
>   db.getLogComponents() displays -1 for the component’s verbosity.